# Не могу понять условие задачи академии Jetbrains по изучению Java. Класc scanner

Tags: java

> Code Challenge — Write a program
>
> Write a program that reads three strings and outputs them in the reverse order, each in a new line.
>
> ```
> Sample Input 1:
> Java
> Programming
> Language
>
> Sample Output 1:   
> Language
> Programming
> Java
> ```

Вот что я попытался сделать в IDEA

```
public class Gava {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String Java = scanner.next(); // "This"
        String Programming = scanner.nextLine(); // " is a simple"
        String Language = scanner.next(); // "multiline"
        String word3 = scanner.next(); // "input,"
        String line2 = scanner.nextLine(); // "
        System.out.println("Language");
        System.out.println("Programming");
        System.out.println("Java");
```

Не могу понять условие задачи.Перелопатил все уже.Туплю,новичок пытась сам решать задачи.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String java = scanner.nextLine();
    String programming = scanner.nextLine();
    String language = scanner.nextLine(); /

    System.out.println(language);
    System.out.println(programming);
    System.out.println(java);
}
```